# Why 2 different entities reference the same object?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-entities, erd

I use **Linq To Entities** to get 2 objects m1 & m2.
And I don't understand why 2 different objects reference the SAME **Template** table.

I suspect that the reason due to the connection between MConfigOnPage1, MConfigOnPage2 with MConfiguration. Maybe it should be splitted somehow?

I attached my ERD and the code.

I'll be grateful for explanation why this happens?

Thank you

```
var cxt = new Entities();
//this returns MConfiguration with Id=19
var m1 = (from mop in cxt.MConfigOnPage1
          where mop.SiteMapId == 15 && mop.HolderId == 13                                         
          select mop.MConfiguration).FirstOrDefault();
//this returns MConfiguration with Id=40    
var m2 = (from mop in cxt.MConfigOnPage2
          where mop.SiteMapId == 15 && mop.HolderId == 1                                         
          select mop.MConfiguration).FirstOrDefault();
  
var t1 = m1.Holder.Template;
var t1.Code = 13;
var t2 = m2.Holder.Template;
//I expect that **t2.Code** to be 0, but it equals 13
//This behavior tells me that m1 & m2 reference the same Template object, 
//   BUT shouldn't m1 & m2 to have their own Template objects?
```

**ERD**

[image: SQL-ERD]
**MConfiguration table data**

[image: MConfiguration_Content]

**Holder table data** ____________________________________________________________________________       **Template table data**

[image: Holder_Content] _____________________________________ [image: Template_Content]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to Entities ensures, within a given context, if you fetch the same entity ( by primary key in DB) you will get the same object.

You will see this same behavior is you selected the row from the template table multiple times. You will always get the same instance back whenever you re-query for any object.

This gives you performance advantages through caching and prevents multiple edits to the same object in the same context from causing conflicts.

Comment: m1 & m2 are fetched from **DIFFERENT** tables, how they can have the same object?

Comment: Its the objects of type Template that I am referring too. In your example t1 and t2 are both referring to the same row in the Template table. Try m1.Holder == m2.Holder && m1.Holder.Template == m2.Holder.Template.